# Scroll overflow element without scrolling into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a child element styled with `overflow-y: auto` that contains a list of other objects. At certain times I need to scroll this list to a particular position, and I have been using `item.scrollIntoView()` which works almost perfectly.

The problem is that `scrollIntoView()` scrolls both the list to the correct position, but also forces the list itself to scroll into view. Is it possible to scroll just the list itself without scrolling the window? *if jQuery is the only simple way, that is also acceptable.*

Comment: jQuery is a library. Not magical. Just slow. And, yes, there's another way.

Comment: I have done this changing the margin of the child element. Like... margin top to  -100px.  Would something like this work for you situation?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that you could simply manipulate the `scrollTop` property of the container.